# Using QTimer.singleShot correctly

Tags: python, pyside

I have the following PySide application, where the intended functionality is to have the text of the `number_button` be updated every 5 seconds, counting from 0 to 9 once the `start_button` has been pressed.

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent)

        self.app_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.app_layout)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 50, 50)

        self.count_to = 10
        self.delay = 5000

        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.setSingleShot(True)

        # start button
        start_button = QtGui.QPushButton()
        start_button.setText('START')
        start_button.clicked.connect(self.startCount)
        self.app_layout.addWidget(start_button)

        # number button
        self.number_button = QtGui.QPushButton()
        self.number_button.setText('0')
        self.app_layout.addWidget(self.number_button)



    def startCount(self):

        def updateButtonCount():
            self.number_button.setText("%s" % count)

        for count in range(0, self.count_to):
            self.timer.singleShot(self.delay, updateButtonCount)


def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    example = Example()
    example.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

However, this results in a `9` appearing after 6 seconds without the intermediate numbers showing at all. I'm pretty sure that the problem is that while the `.singleShot` is running, `count` has already been incremented to its maximum value (`9`).

I can think of a few hack to make this work as intended, but I'd like to fix it in the most effective and appropriate way.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what ``singleShot`` does (and possibly ``Timer`` in general). They're not ``sleep/wait`` methods. They start up a new thread which will periodically (or once, in the case of ``singleShot``) call the given method. So, in your code, you're essentially spinning up 9 timers, all on a 6-second delay, which then call ``updateButtonCount`` once. Since they'll all fire off within one GUI frame, you only see the final ``count`` appear in the button. This is definitely NOT what you want to do.

Comment: I don't have ``Pyside/PyQt`` on this computer or I'd write a proper, tested answer, but the general idea would be to spin up a single ``Timer`` that calls your ``updateButtonCount`` method once per second, and then stop the timer after 9 calls.

Comment: Thanks. It would be good to have your answer! I've asked a related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23867681/waiting-for-a-timer-to-terminate-before-continuing-running-the-code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in the [QTimer](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtCore/QTimer.html#detailed-description) PySide documentation, what you need is a QTimer that will repeatedly time out (every 5 seconds in your case) and call the function `updateButtonCount` once for every timeout - as mentioned by **aruisdante**. Take a look at this:

```
timer = QTimer()  # set up your QTimer
timer.timeout.connect(self.updateButtonCount)  # connect it to your update function
timer.start(5000)  # set it to timeout in 5000 ms
```

With some modifications, the previous code should help you achieve the functionality you want. Keep in mind, `timer.start(5000)` only sets up one timeout to occur in 5000 ms, or **5 seconds**, and your `updateButtonCount` function should include this line at the end if the `QTimer` is to timeout again.

I hope that helps. Feel free to comment if something is not clear.